# c# windows, local database(sql server), connection string not working properly

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce, connection-string

This is my connection string

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WFA1\WFA1\database.sdf");
```

I copied it from the property, I added @ in front but didn't change anything. There are no errors during Build and Run. But when I click insert button, the below error shows up.

"A network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. "

I tried editing connection string and using datadirectory instead of the entire path, but the same error occurs, I am new to .net so I am unable to figure out what could be the cause. I tried google but I can't tell whether the solutions there are related to my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the full SQL Server **2008** version (that would be a  `.mdf` and `.ldf` file) - or are you really using SQL Server **Compact Edition** (which uses a `*.sdf` file)? Your question and tags seem to contradict each other ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong type of SQL connection.  You should be using the [`SqlCeConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class:

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WFA1\WFA1\database.sdf");
```

[Here is a really good reference for SQL CE connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-ce).

Answer (score 1):

The data source for SQL Server is a machine name, not a file name.

You should add a reference to the SQL CE assembly, and do this:

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WFA1\WFA1\database.sdf");
```

Comment: I copied the connection string as it is. I didn't make any change except adding @ in front. Please elaborate the answer.

Comment: You can see that he is using MS SQL Server CE from the .sdf file.  For that, the data source *is* a file name.

Comment: @Dan: Yes, but SqlConnection is for SQL Server NON-ce.

Comment: @Quandry Yes, but a SqlConnection will not work with an SDF file.  That's the whole problem.

Comment: @Dan Yes, that's exactly what i meant, but evidently, it must be spelled out completely.

Answer (score 0):

For MSSQL Server Compact Edition, you should use the `SqlCeConnection` class.

So this should work:

```
SqlCeConnection sqlConnection = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WFA1\WFA1\database.sdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

Create you connection string as follow :

add in the namespace    `using System.Data.SqlServerCe;`

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\admin\documents\visual 
studio 2010\Projects\WFA1\WFA1\database.sdf; Persist Security Info=False;");
```

if `.sdf` file inside you project then you can use :

```
string strConnectionString ="Data Source=" + (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.
GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\database.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;";
SqlCeConnectionconn = new SqlCeConnection(strConnectionString );
```